# Constructor problem in defining Oracle object type using Java class

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql

I've created an object in Oracle based on Java class, but I can't figure out how to define constructor.

For example, I have Java class like this and I'm loading it into Oracle DB:

```
import java.sql.SQLData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLInput;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;

public class Foo implements SQLData {
    public int bar;

    public Foo() {
        this.bar = 0;
    }

    private String sql_type;

    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
        return sql_type;
    }

    @Override
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        bar = stream.readInt();
        sql_type = typeName;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
        stream.writeInt(bar);
    }
}
```

Then in Oracle I'm creating object like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE foo AS OBJECT 
    EXTERNAL NAME 'Foo' LANGUAGE JAVA
    USING SQLDATA(
        bar NUMBER EXTERNAL NAME 'bar',

        CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION foo RETURN SELF AS RESULT EXTERNAL NAME 'Foo() return Foo'
    )
;
```

But I got error like this every time when I try to use it with my constructor:

ORA-29540: Class oracle.aurora.sqljtype.SQLJ7380A743BCB64E4FAFE99F03EBECF627 doesn't exists.

Can Someone explain me how to define constructor when I'm creating Oracle object based on Java class?

Comment: You set bar in your ctor, but not the type String.  It's null if you do nothing to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Your told your default ctor how to initialize the bar int, but you said nothing about type:

```
public class Foo implements SQLData {

    private static final int DEFAULT_BAR = 0;
    private static final String DEFAULT_TYPE = "SOMETHING";

    public int bar;
    private String sql_type;

    public Foo() {
        this(DEFAULT_BAR, DEFAULT_TYPE);
    }

    public Foo(int x, String type) { 
        this.bar = x;
        this.sql_type = type;
    }
}
```

It's null the way you wrote it.  Is that what you want?

Comment: sql_type is initialized by method readSQL while reading stream.

Comment: That is not the constructor.  When you create this object the reference is null until you call your readSQL.   If that's okay, what is your question?

Comment: I don't need to initialize it in constructor. It's only for Oracle use. I am asking how to define constructor in Oracle DB object created from Java class.